# Criteria for orientation of surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, orientation

I'm actually studying multivariable calculus and its big theorems like divergence theorem and stoke's theorem.

I am lost in the criteria to decide when the orientation of the unit out normal to a surface is compatible with the orientation of the line integral of the surface's boundary.

Can some one explain more on this? How do i decide when they are compatible?

Comment: The surface should be to your left as you walk around the closed curve if the normal is pointing up with respect to you. I would check out the mit open courseware videos on stokes theorem.

Comment: Here is the lecture https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=tzoYhe3H5dM.